# Resultado estranho de conta matemática simples do javascritpt

Tags: javascript

Tenho um script simples que deve fazer a subtração de 3 valores. O problema é que no notei que algumas vezes a operação deveria me dar um resultado 0 mas me dá um resultado com um número totalmente estranho. Eu até fiz direto no console com os valores e mesmo assim me deu esse resultado estranho. 
Ex:

```
valor_restante = valor_liquido - valor_digitado - valor_acertado;
```

nesse código acima os valores seriam:

```
valor_restante = 1916.64 - 916.64 - 1000;
```

O resultado da operação deveria ser 0 mas o valor fica

> 1.1368683772161603e-13

Alguém sabe dizer porque o javascript faz isso e como resolver?

Comment: Esse formato de número é notação científica (exponencial, em potencias de dez), significa `0.00000000000011368683772161603` - floats não são números exatos, então sempre que usar para lugares onde precisa de exatidão, vai ter problema. Leia as postagens linkadas acima para entender melhor. Se vai trabalhar com dinheiro, procure usar centavos em vez de reais, para trabalhar com inteiros. (voce pode exibir a virgula apenas na hora da exibição na tela) - Isso não é uma característica do Javascript, e sim do tipo numérico usado. Acontece em praticamente qualquer linguagem.

Comment: Entendi. Eu fiz `Math.round((valor_liquido - valor_digitado - valor_acertado)*100)/100;` de acordo com o que foi sugerido no primeiro tópico e resolveu pra mim. Obrigado.

Comment: Não é a melhor solução, vai dar erro de centavo em certas situações. Se é pra fazer isso vc vai primeiro multiplicar cada um por cem e arredondar, fazer a conta e só depois dividir.